# Drop row in Pandas dataframe if matching multiple values

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a .csv into a dataframe and pushing it to a SQL database successfully.  Unfortunately, the csv has several rows that I want to drop before I ship it off to the SQL database.  Several solutions I have tried just have not worked and I am stuck.

example .csv

```
Name,Organization,Lifecycle Environment,Subscription Quantity,Subscription SKU
Host1,MyORG,Library,500,NRS2718
Host1,MyOrg,Library,-1,155425976806
Host2,MyOrg,DEV,250,NRS2718
Host2,MyOrg,DEV,-1,361867226799
```

I need to remove the rows that contain the values 155425976806 and 361867226799 for a dataframe with

```
Name,Organization,Lifecycle Environment,Subscription Quantity,Subscription SKU
Host1,MyORG,Library,500,NRS2718
Host2,MyOrg,DEV,250,NRS2718
```

My code that does not drop a single row

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")

quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=10.1.1.11;uid=myuser;pwd=mypass;DATABASE=LICENSES")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

indexSKU = df[ (df['Subscription SKU'] == 155425976806) & (df['Subscription SKU'] == 361867226799)].index
df.drop(indexSKU , inplace=True)

df.to_sql('DataTable', if_exists = 'replace', schema='dbo', con=engine)

result = engine.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[DataTable]')
result.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The numbers are `str` type so you need to search for them as strings.

  - Use `map(str, [...])` to convert all the numeric values in a list of unwanted numbers, to `str` type.
- Use a [Boolean search](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and negate it with `~`, since you want rows without those values.

```py
# read the data in
df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")

# use a Boolean mask to exclude the values
df = df[~df['Subscription SKU'].isin(map(str, [155425976806, 361867226799]))]

# display(df)
    Name Organization Lifecycle Environment  Subscription Quantity Subscription SKU
0  Host1        MyORG               Library                    500          NRS2718
2  Host2        MyOrg                   DEV                    250          NRS2718
```